# strong convexity of loss function in multi-dimensional (high-dimensional) space

Tags: calculus, statistics, optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning

My question is based on this [paper](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/papers/SridharanShSr08.pdf) (see the last 10 rows in page 7). It seems this is a general claim:

In machine learning or statistic,  the loss function $l(W^TX, y)$ (a linear predictor) can never be strongly convex in a multi-dimensional space, even if $l(\cdot)$ is strongly
convex, since it is ﬂat in directions orthogonal to $X$.

How to get the meaning of this claim?

Comment: It's actually pretty simple. Let $\Delta W$ be orthogonal to $X$. Then
$l((W+t\Delta W)^TX,y)=l(W^TX,y)$ for all $t$. It's constant along that direction, so it cannot be a strongly convex function.

Answer (score 0):

In high dimensions, $X^T$ would be rank deficient and have a non-trivial kernel, ensuring the existence of $\Delta W \in null(X^T)-\{0\}$. Now plug this $\Delta W$ in Michael's illustration, and we're done.